# How to use python numpy.savetxt to write strings and float number to an ASCII file?

Tags: python, list, numpy, output

I have a set of lists that contain both strings and float numbers, such as:

```
import numpy as num

NAMES  = num.array(['NAME_1', 'NAME_2', 'NAME_3'])
FLOATS = num.array([ 0.5    , 0.2     , 0.3     ])

DAT =  num.column_stack((NAMES, FLOATS))
```

I want to stack these two lists together and write them to a text file in the form of columns; therefore, I want to use **numpy.savetxt** (if possible) to do this.

```
num.savetxt('test.txt', DAT, delimiter=" ")
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
>>> num.savetxt('test.txt', DAT, delimiter=" ") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_9597b1f_20120920-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1047, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.string_
```

The ideal output file would look like:

```
NAME_1    0.5
NAME_2    0.2
NAME_3    0.3
```

How can I write both strings and float numbers to a text file, possibly avoiding using csv ( I want to make if readable for other people )? Is there another way of doing this instead of using **numpy.savetxt**?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You have to specify the format (`fmt`) of you data in `savetxt`, in this case as a string (`%s`):

```
num.savetxt('test.txt', DAT, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

The default format is a float, that is the reason it was expecting a float instead of a string and explains the error message.

Comment: And what happens if I want to format the numbers? How can I give some format to the numbers only?

Comment: You can give different formats to different columns, like `fmt="%f %i"`. But if you want to combine it with strings as in the example above, you will need a structured array (see [here](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/using-numpy-savetxt-to-save-columns-of-numerical-values-and-columns-of-text-values-td12304.html#none)). In this example, the int is converted to a string, and then formatting as an int is not possible anymore.

Answer (score 40):

The currently accepted answer does not actually address the question, which asks how to save lists that contain both strings and float numbers. For completeness I provide a fully working example, which is based, with some modifications, on the link given in @joris comment.

```
import numpy as np

names  = np.array(['NAME_1', 'NAME_2', 'NAME_3'])
floats = np.array([ 0.1234 ,  0.5678 ,  0.9123 ])

ab = np.zeros(names.size, dtype=[('var1', 'U6'), ('var2', float)])
ab['var1'] = names
ab['var2'] = floats

np.savetxt('test.txt', ab, fmt="%10s %10.3f")
```

**Update:** This example also works properly in Python 3 by using the `'U6'` Unicode string [dtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), when creating the `ab` [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), instead of the `'S6'` byte string. The latter dtype would work in Python 2.7, but would write strings like `b'NAME_1'` in Python 3.

Comment: What if I had a bidimensional floats array and wanted to print each name with its correspondent array? Would the only way be adding all the rows manually or is there a simpler way to do that? 
Expected output: NAME_1 0.1 0.2 0.3

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

a = 'a,b,c'

b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(a + '\n')
    np.savetxt(f, b, delimiter=',', fmt='%f')



The output file would look like this:
a,b,c
1.000000,2.000000,3.000000
4.000000,5.000000,6.000000
```

This example is for numpy.savetxt to write strings and float numbers to file, especially for strings that are written in rows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a header parameter:

```
np.savetxt(file, data, delimiter=',', header='TimeStamp,X,Z', fmt='%s,%.2f,%d')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).