# Which argument is required for np.savetxt to output float data?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a little piece of code which is running well, however I am struggling to determine a way of outputting it into a .txt file. Here is the code:

```
with open("Coord") as f:
    line=f.readline()
    for line in f:
        coords=map(float,line.split(" "))
        if poly.contains(Point(coords[0],coords[1])):
            print line
```

The print command works and displays what I need in the terminal, however I just can't manage to find a way to save this yet. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
np.savetxt('inside.txt', np.vstack((line.str())).T)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

---

```
np.savetxt('inside.txt', line)

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

---

```
np.savetxt('inside.txt', np.transpose([line])

TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.string_
```

---

```
np.savetxt('inside.txt', line, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

---

I am still quite inexperienced at python and code in general and was hoping somebody could explain the correct formatting to be used here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to check [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621351/how-to-use-python-numpy-savetxt-to-write-strings-and-float-number-to-an-ascii-fi).

Comment: I already checked both before posting. The other thread is where I got my 4th listed attempt from and I was unable to solve it from the documentation. I just tried ...fmt="%f" but it didn't work either.

Comment: Just to be sure - is the `line` numpy array object here `np.savetxt('inside.txt', line)` ? Can you show its data?

Comment: @erthalion I can use the command "print line" after having performed the rest of my code and it displays exactly what I desire on the terminal screen - I just can't figure out how to save this data to a text file.

Comment: @Vlad `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'` this means, that `line` is a string (and for sure, it's a line of file). But as you can see in documentation, `np.savetxt` requires numpy array as second argument, not just a string.

Comment: @erthalion Forgive me if I am being obtuse here, but isn't that what I did in my final attempt? `np.savetxt('inside.txt', line, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")` Is there something simple that I am missing?

Comment: @Vlad no, `delimiter` and `fmt` options just describe an output file format ("inside.txt" in this case), not `line` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) , you can clearly see that `np.savetext` requires an `array_like` object as the second argument.

You can try converting `line` into an `array` before saving , something like -

```
np.savetxt('inside.txt', np.array(line.split(" ")), delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

Comment: As a small test you can try using `np.savetxt('inside.txt', line.split(" "), delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")` , we can check if it would accept list as input as well or not , my guess is no, but if by any luck if it does, we can avoid the overhead call to `np.array()`