# Error for saving a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, import

I have a matrix containing string, float and int numbers and i want to save it as a csv file. This is the command that i use:

```
numpy.savetxt("X.csv", X, delimiter=",")
```

Where X is name of the matrix. This is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1073, in savetxt
fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: float argument required, not str
```

This is the first row of matrix:

```
16  disk    11  10.29   4.63    30.22 11  20.49   60.60   20.22 11  22.17   0.71    10.37
```

and type of matrix is numpy.ndarray.

How can i save it? Thanks

Comment: Tell us more about `X` (`dtype` for example).  Have you explored the `fmt` parameter for `savetxt`?

Comment: Can you include an example of that this matrix contains?  I just did `X = np.matrix( np.random.uniform( 0,1, (4,4)) );
np.savetxt("X.csv", X, delimiter=",") ` and it works just fine.

Comment: @hpaulj Could u please explain how i should use fmt in this case?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: How would you format your row sample? `%s, %s, %d, %f,etc'`%(row)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you give, the matrix is composed of strings as well as floats. Then this question has already been answered here:

[How to use python numpy.savetxt to write strings and float number to an ASCII file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621351/how-to-use-python-numpy-savetxt-to-write-strings-and-float-number-to-an-ascii-fi)

Edit your `np.savetxt` call to be `numpy.savetxt("X.csv", X, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')`

Comment: The `'%s'` fmt says - convert each column to its usual string representation.