# Numpy savetxt error

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, arcpy

Below is the code I am struggling with as a beginner:

```
commonfields = arcpy.ListFields(gt_pnts)
names = [f.name for f in commonfields]
needed_names = names[3:]

gt_pnts_arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(gt_pnts, needed_names)
gt_pnts_arr = gt_pnts_arr.reshape((gt_pnts_arr.shape[0],1))
eq_smpled_pnts_arr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(eq_smpled_pnts, needed_names)
eq_smpled_pnts_arr = eq_smpled_pnts_arr.reshape((eq_smpled_pnts_arr.shape[0],1))
master_table = np.concatenate((gt_pnts_arr, eq_smpled_pnts_arr), axis=0)
np.savetxt(outputcsvfilename,master_table, fmt="%.1f")
```

Error is as below:

> TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.void

I searched and found this exception raised when datatype is not defined. But when I test as below I am in the dilemma-

```
>>>master_table.dtype.descr
>>>[('grid_code', '<i4'), ('b1_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b2_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b3_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b4_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b5_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b6_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b7_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b8_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b9_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b10_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b11_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b12_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('b13_Clip_ProximityRaster1', '<f4'), ('resp', '<U2')]
>>>master_table
array([[ (13, 13.0, 3810.0, 3810.0, 1982.952392578125, 3873.71923828125, 34869.9140625, 5483.3564453125, 7272.138671875, 4409.591796875, 872.0665283203125, 36238.62109375, 4441.62109375, 6775.2861328125, u'1')],
       [ (1, 1.0, 3601.99951171875, 3603.12353515625, 1626.9295654296875, 3725.922607421875, 34595.9453125, 5810.5595703125, 7592.90478515625, 4476.0361328125, 576.2811889648438, 36462.984375, 4499.0, 7164.47509765625, u'1')],
       [ (13, 13.0, 3721.93505859375, 3723.02294921875, 1642.3458251953125, 3842.928466796875, 34713.43359375, 5702.3681640625, 7597.17041015625, 4562.07177734375, 657.9513549804688, 36343.12890625, 4586.9599609375, 7111.0126953125, u'1')],.....................
>>>master_table.shape
>>>(50, 1)
>>>gt_pnts_arr.shape
>>>(25, 1)
```

Even I can not load this `master_table` into pandas dataframe as below-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=master_table[1:,1:], index=master_table[1:,0],columns=master_table[0,1:])
```

**My table datatypes:
There are 13 colums and 50 rows in the `master_table`.First and last column datatype is respectively integer and integer but all other(11) data type is float.**

Comment: looks to me like your `master_table` is non numerical because of the last column of `u'1'`'s, and it also contains python tuples instead of being multidimensional with floats. You probably just need to reformat your data...

Comment: @JulienBernu Ok edited the question. You are right!

Comment: 2d numeric arrays are easiest for `savetxt`. It can handle 1d structured arrays also, but getting the `fmt` right can trickier. The code isn't complicated - just iterate and format the 'row' with `fmt%tuple(row)`.  The numpy void is a record of your structured array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36509122/901925

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35209070/901925

Answer (score 1):

Recreating your data (thaxs for enough information), I make a `data` array

```
In [33]: data.shape
Out[33]: (3, 1)
In [34]: len(data.dtype.fields)
```

Trying `savetxt`:

```
In [28]: np.savetxt('test.csv',data, fmt="%.1f")
-> 1158   fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
   1159      except TypeError:

TypeError: cannot convert to a float; scalar object is not a number
```

and a secondary error:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype .... and format specifier ('%.1f')
```

`savetxt` iterates on `data`

```
for row in data:
    f.write(fmt%tuple(row))
```

But with this shape `row` is a (1,) array.

But if I get rid of the unnecessary 2nd dimension (size 1)

```
In [37]: np.savetxt('test.csv',data[:,0], fmt="%.1f")
TypeError: a float is required
```

and

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype .... and format specifier ('%.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f')
```

Note that is has taken your `fmt`, and replicated it to match the number of fields.  Copy that last format specifier, and tweak it to work with the final string column

```
In [38]: fmt='%.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %.1f %s'
```

Now it works:

```
In [39]: np.savetxt('test.csv',data[:,0], fmt=fmt)
In [40]: cat test.csv
13.0 13.0 3810.0 3810.0 1983.0 3873.7 34869.9 5483.4 7272.1 4409.6 872.1 36238.6 4441.6 6775.3 1
1.0 1.0 3602.0 3603.1 1626.9 3725.9 34595.9 5810.6 7592.9 4476.0 576.3 36463.0 4499.0 7164.5 1
13.0 13.0 3721.9 3723.0 1642.3 3842.9 34713.4 5702.4 7597.2 4562.1 658.0 36343.1 4587.0 7111.0 1
```

So there are 2 corrections - a structured array has to be 1d to work with `savetxt` - rows and fields.  And the `fmt` has to work with the dtype.  In this case you have to handle the string field.

If the last field had been numeric (e.g. int) as opposed to `U2`, the `data[:,0]` would have worked with the simple `%.1f` fmt.  The initial int field saves just fine (though the fmt could also be tweaked for that).