# Saving data using numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, file, numpy, save

I have numpy array I. I am writing it in a file using:

```
np.savetxt(fp, I[None], fmt='%e', delimiter=',')
```

It is writing array in a file each value separated by a comma. Now I want to append one more column after I. So how can I append some non-array data values in the same row.

Comment: Do you know about `structured` arrays?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507283/shape-of-a-structured-array-in-numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is to just concatenate the extra data and write with `%s` to handle the text

```
In [97]: I = np.arange(5)
In [98]: I[None]
Out[98]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])


In [101]: np.savetxt('test',I[None],delimiter=',', fmt='%e')
In [102]: cat test
0.000000e+00,1.000000e+00,2.000000e+00,3.000000e+00,4.000000e+00
```

now to add a text column:

```
In [103]: lbl = np.array([['test']])
In [105]: np.hstack((I[None],lbl))
Out[105]: array([['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'test']], dtype='<U21')
```

This is now all string, so you'll have to write with '%s':

```
In [106]: np.savetxt('test',_,delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
In [107]: cat test
0,1,2,3,4,test
```

Or make an `object` dtype array, and apply a custom fmt to each column:

```
In [108]: lbl = np.array([['test']],object)
In [109]: np.hstack((I[None],lbl))
Out[109]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'test']], dtype=object)
In [110]: np.savetxt('test',_,fmt='%d, %e, %e, %e, %e, %s')
In [111]: cat test
0, 1.000000e+00, 2.000000e+00, 3.000000e+00, 4.000000e+00, test
```

I've also recommended making a structured array, though this object dtype might be easier to use.

```
In [112]: dt = np.dtype('i,f,f,f,f,U10')
In [113]: arr = np.array([tuple(Out[109][0])],dt)
In [114]: arr
Out[114]: 
array([(0, 1., 2., 3., 4., 'test')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4'), ('f4', '<f4'), ('f5', '<U10')])
In [115]: np.savetxt('test',_,fmt='%d, %e, %e, %e, %e, %s')
In [116]: cat test
0, 1.000000e+00, 2.000000e+00, 3.000000e+00, 4.000000e+00, test
```

`savetxt` iterates on the 1st dimension of the input array, and writes it using your `fmt` (or one constructed from your `fmt`).  If you are familiar enough with Python formatting and file writing, you could do the same - and it would run just as fast.

Answer (score 0):

You could just edit the textfile and add the non-array data values that way:

```
np.savetxt(fp, I[None], fmt='%e', delimiter=',')
with open(fp,'a') as f:
    f.write("non-array data values")
```