# How to write datetime data in a list to a csv file in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, listview, datetime

Here's a basic question for you guys, but I have searched but not found the answer around this and other sites.

I want to write data collected in for example two lists, let's say every 15minutes, one list for data from a sensor and the other for the logging date and time. The problem is that I can't find the correct datetime format to be written into the csv file. Here's a short verion of my code, with random data instead of sensor data, and the currend date.time instead of waiting 15 min.

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import csv
import datetime
a=[]
b=[]
for p in range (1,20):
   i = datetime.datetime.now()
   i=i.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
   i=str(i) #also tried without this line
   a.append(i)
   b.append(randint(0,26))  
   np.savetxt('data.csv', (a,b),delimiter=',')
```

Gives two errors. 'A float is required' and 'Mismatch between array dtype ('<19') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e,...). 
I would really appreciate hints on this.

Answer (score 0):

try this  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621351/how-to-use-python-numpy-savetxt-to-write-strings-and-float-number-to-an-ascii-fi)

if you find any issue please let me know.it's working fine for me.

Comment: I still want to save to a csv file, but what I did was take the advice on adding (..., fmt="%s"). And it worked! It was also easy to imort to an excel and Libre Calc. Thanks a lot!

Comment: import numpy as np
from random import randint
import csv
import datetime
a=[]
b=[]
for p in range (1,20):
   i = datetime.datetime.now()
   i=i.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
   i=str(i) #also tried without this line
   a.append(i)
   b.append(randint(0,26))
   DAT =  np.column_stack((a, b))
   np.savetxt('data.csv', DAT,delimiter=',' ,fmt='%s')